# Maximum number of columns / values you can INSERT INTO a table - mysql

Tags: mysql, insert-into

Does anybody know what's the maximum number of columns/values you can *insert into* a table (mysql)? I get an error for... IDK... 20 columns/values? (yes, #_of_col = #no_of_val)

```
INSERT INTO comenzi (a,b,c,d,e,f,...) 
VALUES (1,2,3,4,5,6,...)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have more than 20 columns in a table so I don't think that is your problem.

Most likely you have the wrong number of columns in your values list or one of your column names is a keyword.

You said you've already checked that number of values is correct. In my experience counting 20 things by hand is very difficult so you might want to double-check that you've counted correctly.

But assuming that isn't the problem then I'd guess that it's probably because one of your column names is a reserved keyword. Surrounding your column names with backticks prevents them being parsed incorrectly:

```
INSERT INTO comenzi (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`, ...) 
VALUES (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...)
```

You should also make sure that if you have any strings in your value list that they are quoted and properly escaped if necessary.

Comment: by "did it" I mean "wrapping column names in `` did the trick"

Answer (score 9):

The hard limit is 4096 columns per table, with a maximum row size of 65,535 bytes (Source: [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/column-count-limit.html)).

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question. People who find this question from Google will appreciate it. :)

Comment: @Mark ... and +1 for understanding and fixing the OP's problem, without much input. @nush surely appreciates :)